dredge with occuMulti
Is the dredge function from MuMIn incompatible with occuMulti objects, and if so, why? I would like to dredge a global model to create unique multispecies occupancy models with all possible combinations of my covariates (64 combinations total, based on this approach), but I am getting the error
Error in getAllTerms.unmarkedFit(global.model, intercept = TRUE, data = eval(gmCall$data,: unknown 'unmarkedFit' fit type: occuMulti
Here is a simple, reproducible example:
library(unmarked)
library(MuMIn)

# Simulate multispecies occupancy data
set.seed(123)
n_sites <- 100  # number of sites
n_surveys <- 3  # number of surveys per site

# Simulated site-level covariates (e.g., habitat characteristics)
covariates <- data.frame(
  water = rnorm(n_sites, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  forest = rnorm(n_sites, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  elevation = rnorm(n_sites, mean = 0, sd = 1)
)

# Simulated detection histories for two species
species1 <- matrix(rbinom(n_sites * n_surveys, 1, 0.5), nrow = n_sites)
species2 <- matrix(rbinom(n_sites * n_surveys, 1, 0.4), nrow = n_sites)

# Create unmarkedFrameOccuMulti object
umf_multi <- unmarkedFrameOccuMulti(
  y = list(species1 = species1, species2 = species2),
  siteCovs = covariates,
  obsCovs = NULL
)

# Fit global multispecies occupancy model
global_model <- occuMulti(
  detformulas = c(~ 1, ~ 1),  # Detection formula for both species (intercept-only)
  stateformulas = c(~ water + forest + elevation,  # State formula for species 1
                    ~ water + forest + elevation), # State formula for species 2
  data = umf_multi
)

# Dredge the global model 
dredge_model <- dredge(global_model, rank=AIC)            #Error occurs here
summary(dredge_model)

